# Nesting shortcodes in Wordpress results in the inner shortcode being placed AFTER outer shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to use nested shortcodes, but i'm having problems with it.

Everytime i try to nest two shortcodes created by me...

First declared in functions.php (the inner):

```
function p_generic_shortcode( $atts , $content = null )
{
    return '<p class="pov generic">' . do_shortcode($content) . '</p>';
}
add_shortcode( 'pov-generic', 'p_generic_shortcode' );
```

Second declared in functions.php (the outer):

```
function f_girl_shortcode( $atts , $content = null )
{
    return '<p class="talk girl">' . do_shortcode($content) . '</p>';
}
add_shortcode( 'talk-girl', 'f_girl_shortcode' );
```

When i enter the following code in bbpress editor:

```
[talk-girl]TEXT[pov-generic]OTHER TEXT[/pov-generic][/talk-girl]
```

It outputs the follow code:

```
<p class="talk girl">TEXT</p>
<p class="pov generic">OTHER TEXT</p>
```

And not as i expected:

```
<p class="talk girl">TEXT<p class="pov generic">OTHER TEXT</p></p>
```

Comment: It works in clean WP, have you used any plugin which handles output buffering?

Comment: I use bbpress (don't support natively custom wordpress bbcodes) and a plugin to "force" bbpress to do shortcodes [link](http://pippinsplugins.com/bbpress-do-shortcodes)

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED.
According with [This answer in WP StackOverflow](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/185765/71362) all the trouble was because i tried to nest two p elements, and WP wont let me do this. Changing the child shortcode with a span solves that.